# Cannot resolve NoReverseMatch error in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and try to make a quick search engine, but I have this error and cannot fix it after reading Django documentation. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

This is the error:

```
Reverse for 'search' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<name>[^/]+)$']
```

My codes are as below:

layout.html

```
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'encyclopedia:search' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:name>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("<str:name>", views.search, name="search")
]
```

views.py

```
def search(request, searched_name):
    """
    Deal with search engine on the left widget
    """
    result = util.get_entry(searched_name)

    if result:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('encyclopedia:entry', args=(result)))
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
        "error_name": "Requested page not found"
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second and third urls the same that's why only one pattern is tried and given the pattern named **search** isn't the first one, django is unable to find a reverse match. The URLs aren't well thought as they will both match any string after the root of the domain and this will definitely become a nightmare as your project grows bigger. Consider having them as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("entry/<str:name>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search/<str:name>", views.search, name="search")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your `urls.py`, you need to `name` in URL itself.

I will suggest you to remove `name` from urls.py and get in views via form data. Please see an example below

urls.py -> `path("search/", views.search, name="search")`

```
def search(request):
    """
    Deal with search engine on the left widget
    """
    result = util.get_entry(request.POST.get('q', None))

    if result:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('encyclopedia:entry', args=(result)))
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
        "error_name": "Requested page not found"
    })
```

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot. I just got confused how to transfer the parameter 'q' into views.py